# Google script change a value in my array unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I am stuck with a part of my google script code where one of array elements changed unexpectedly. It looks like a bug to me, but I'd like to hear from here if it's really is or just my coding error that I overlooked. Of course, I'm hoping for a solution as well in any case.

Here is that part of the code.

```
  if (chkIn) {arr[1] = importData[i][1]+'2';
             } else {

               Logger.log((i)+'   '+importData[i][1]);
               Logger.log((i+1)+'   '+importData[i+1][1]);
               Logger.log((i+2)+'   '+importData[i+2][1]);
               Logger.log(arr[1]);

               arr[1] = importData[i][1]+'1';

               Logger.log('---------------------------------------------------');
               Logger.log((i)+'   '+importData[i][1]);
               Logger.log((i+1)+'   '+importData[i+1][1]);
               Logger.log((i+2)+'   '+importData[i+2][1]);
               Logger.log(arr[1]);
             };
```

(The if statement doesn't seem relevant here, but I included it just in case.)

Here is the output.

```
2573   2017122103
2574   20171221041
2575   20171221042
20171221042
---------------------------------------------------
2573   2017122103
2574   20171221041
2575   20171221031
20171221031
```

I really have no idea how `importData[i+2][1]` changed its value to `arr[1]` (the number after 2575).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please show what `arr` is?

Comment: It's because you are reassigning it here (between logs): `arr[1] = importData[i][1]+'1';`

Comment: @JaromandaX I use `arr` to store values from `importData` before re-insert it into `importData` (using `splice`).
`Logger.log(arr);` gives the following results where some_string are texts I rather not show here.
  
  
`[Thu Dec 21 00:00:00 GMT+07:00 2017, 20171221042, 100.0, some_string, , , -3383.25, , some_string, some_string]`

Comment: @Kos My understanding is that the `statement arr[1] = importData[i][1]+'1';` would change the value of `arr[1]`, not `importData[i+2][1]`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Poon `splice` returns removed items from an array, `slice` returns a copy. Your issue is probably similar to the duplicate question.

Comment: @Kos 
@SalmanA 
Yeah. I think you're right. I kind of guess it has something to do with `splice` as well, but cannot find any docs that answer this behavior of it (perhaps I didn't know what to look for exactly at the beginning). Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is because in your case:

```
arr === importData[i+2]
```

So when you change `arr[1]` you also have changed `importData[i+2][1]`.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't known about `splice` in array well enough. Lesson learned.